# Npgsql locks thread indefinitely in async environment

Tags: c#, multithreading, postgresql, npgsql, orleans

I'm struggling to find an answer to a problem I've been experiencing with C#'s popular Postgres library, Npgsql. I'm not sure if it's wholly a problem with Npgsql or not, though I suspect it is because my code is very straight forward. The issue I'm seeing is: when I call an async method on Npgsql sometimes, not all the time, the thread becomes locked. This issue occurs randomly from what I can tell. The result, being that I'm running in a Microsoft Orleans environment (which may be relevant to finding the solution), is that the thread locks indefinitely, thus making one of Orleans' worker threads unable to process work. As I make more Npgsql calls, these locked threads stack up and eventually the Orleans system is choked by thread exhaustion.

So I'm really at a loss for what the problem could be, but because the locking always happens in the same method, and because it appears to be happening in some subroutine of Npgsql, I think it's fair to investigate Npgsql further.

Here's my code which is used in an Orleans storage provider (special class which handles the system's persistence layer.)

```
var sql = $"SELECT * FROM objects WHERE id = @id";

using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    try
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);

        using(var reader = await connection.ExecuteReaderAsync(cmd))
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                var objects = await ProtobufSQL.DataReaderToType(modelType, reader);
                var data = objects[0];
                state.Data = data;
            }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Error(1, e.Message, e);
    }
}
```

This is the source for the ProtobufSQL class:

```
public class ProtobufSQL
{
    public static List<Tuple<string, object>> FlattenToSQLColumns(IMessage message, MessageDescriptor descriptor, string prefix = null)
    {
        var fields = descriptor.Fields.InDeclarationOrder();

        var columns = new List<Tuple<string, object>>();

        for (var i = 0; i < fields.Count; i++)
        {
            var field = fields[i];
            var columnName = field.Name.ToLower();

            if (field.Name == "id")
            {
                ByteString bytes = (ByteString)field.Accessor.GetValue(message);
                var uuid = new Guid(bytes.ToByteArray());
                columns.Add(new Tuple<string, object>("id", uuid));
            }
            else if (field.FieldType == FieldType.Message)
            {
                var embeddedDescriptor = field.MessageType;
                var embeddedMessage = field.Accessor.GetValue(message);
                if (field.IsRepeated)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Repeated complex types are not supported, create a foreign key reference in a new object instead.");
                }
                else
                {
                    columns.AddRange(FlattenToSQLColumns((IMessage)embeddedMessage, embeddedDescriptor, $"{columnName}."));
                }
            }
            else if (field.FieldType == FieldType.Group)
            {
                throw new Exception("Groups are not supported by ProtobufSQL.");
            }
            else
            {
                var columnValue = field.Accessor.GetValue(message);
                var key = prefix + columnName;
                if (field.IsRepeated)
                {
                    var enumerableColumnValue = columnValue as IEnumerable;
                    Type listTypeOf = enumerableColumnValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(listTypeOf);
                    dynamic valueList = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
                    foreach (var item in enumerableColumnValue)
                    {
                        valueList.Add((dynamic)item);
                    }
                    columns.Add(new Tuple<string, object>(key, valueList.ToArray()));
                }
                else
                {
                    columns.Add(new Tuple<string, object>(key, columnValue));
                }
            }
        }

        return columns;
    }

    public static async Task<IMessage[]> DataReaderToType(Type type, DbDataReader reader)
    {
        var descriptor = (MessageDescriptor)type.GetProperty("Descriptor").GetValue(null);

        IList<IMessage> objects = new List<IMessage>();

        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            TraverseDbRow(reader, descriptor, obj);
            objects.Add((IMessage)obj);
        }

        return objects.ToArray();
    }

    private static void TraverseDbRow(DbDataReader reader, MessageDescriptor descriptor, object obj, string prefix = null)
    {
        var fields = descriptor.Fields.InFieldNumberOrder();

        for (var i = 0; i < fields.Count; i++)
        {
            var field = fields[i];
            if (field.FieldType == FieldType.Message)
            {
                if (field.IsRepeated)
                {
                    // Repeated embedded types will be broken out into a separate table,
                    // so there's no need to handle them here.
                }
                else if (field.IsMap)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Maps are not yet supported by ProtobufSQL.");
                }
                else
                {
                    var embeddedDescriptor = field.MessageType;
                    var embeddedObj = Activator.CreateInstance(embeddedDescriptor.ClrType);
                    TraverseDbRow(reader, embeddedDescriptor, embeddedObj, $"{prefix}{field.Name}.");
                }
            }
            else if (field.FieldType == FieldType.Group)
            {
                throw new Exception("Groups are not supported by ProtobufSQL.");
            }
            else
            {
                var columnName = prefix + field.Name;
                try
                {
                    var columnValue = reader[columnName];
                    var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(field.Name, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                    if (field.Name == "id")
                    {
                        var guid = (Guid)columnValue;
                        ByteString bytes = ByteString.CopyFrom(guid.ToByteArray());
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, bytes);
                    }
                    else if (field.IsRepeated)
                    {
                        var repeated = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj);
                        var addRange = repeated.GetType().GetMethod("AddRange");
                        addRange.Invoke(repeated, new object[] { columnValue });
                    }
                    else if (field.IsMap)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Maps are not yet supported by ProtobufSQL.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(columnValue, propertyInfo.PropertyType));
                    }
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
                {
                    // columnName was not present in the response
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have this screenshot of the thread's stack when it got locked: [image: thread stack]

I'm really unsure what to make of all this. Hopefully someone is out there with a bit of knowledge that can help me proceed! Thanks.

Comment: What is ProtobufSQL.DataReaderToType? If that is your custom method - worth including its source code.

Comment: @Evk Added, thanks.

Comment: Your stack trace is also not full (there is a scrollbar).

Comment: @Evk Added! It's quite long as it's running inside Orleans.

Comment: Seems like this line may be related, if I understand async C# correctly. https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/87e861e326e9df5282b2f35253ccca69db9791b0/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlDataReader.cs#L722

Tracked here: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1491

Comment: Yes that is definetely deadlock caused by blocking in async code by calling Wait() or Result.